# Phonegap: Custom URL handling freezing

Tags: javascript, iphone, oauth, cordova

I'm developing an iphone app using PhoneGap 1.2.0 with Snow Leopard, Xcode 4.2 & running in the iPhone simulator.  I connect to a 3rd-party website via Oauth and need to redirect to my app with the attached values.  Following Jesse's [guide here](http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2011/03/07/supporting-custom-urls-in-phonegap-iphone-apps-pt-2-of-2/), I have the following code:

```
// Objective-C code in your AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    // Do something with the url here
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleOpenURL(\"%@\");", url];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];  // freezes here

    return YES;
}


// JS code loaded in your webview
function handleOpenURL(url)
{
    // TODO: do something with the url passed in.
    alert(url);
}
```

The Objective C code lives in "AppDelegate.m" and the JS code is in a separate JS file referenced in index.html.  The app freezes at the 'webView' line.  I believe the issue has to do when something not loading properly - any ideas?  When the app is frozen, if I click the iPhone button, then click the app icon, the app reloads and the 'handleOpenUrl' JS method runs as desired with the alert.

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue, would like an solution. Tested only in the simulator as of now.

Comment: @MarcusJoe I hope my answer helps you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution - inspired by this PhoneGap [Google group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/18b2bd1d57199979/b0a26328ce56a03a?lnk=gst&q=stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString#b0a26328ce56a03a).  From what I can tell, PhoneGap is executing the "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" method before the webview can load, hence the freezing issue.  Using the window.setTimeout function, we can ensure that the app has sufficient time to load:

```
// Objective-C code in your AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    // Do something with the url here
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@
          "window.setTimeout(function() { \n"
          "handleOpenURL(\"%@\"); \n"
          "},1);", url];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in PhoneGap (Cordova) 2.0. modified the above code in AppDelegate.m and it worked great :D

Comment: @SomethingOn awesome! Happy to hear that it worked for you too.

Comment: What about a cold start? This work great for an app running in the background, but doesn't work when the app is being started for the first time as per my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515096/how-do-i-handle-a-custom-url-scheme-in-phonegap-for-a-cold-start

Answer (score 0):

I believe a colleague of mine once mentioned that url's containing "-" characters caused problems, are there any "-" or "_" in the url?

Comment: hmm... this is Netflix's API, returning oauth_token and oauth_verifier - so yes.  the url in 'handleOpenURL' method is: myApp://?oauth_token=[VALUES]&oauth_verifier=

Comment: Sorry, don't think that is the issue.  I tried setting jsString to "handleOpenURL("test")" (i.e. no dashes or underscores) but with no luck.

Comment: Ah k. too bad. was a long shot

Answer (score 0):

Custom URL handling is now part of Cordova library, see here:
[Cordova Custom URL Scheme Handling](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Custom-URL-Handling)

Comment: Still requires adding the setTimeout as of 2.3. Not sure how they added the feature without it actually working, but they did.

Comment: Phonegap/Cordova 3 is still having issues.  Solution that involves editing the AppDelegate.m file is the only solution I've found still.

Answer (score -1):

And with Cordova 1.7.0, hacked code in AppDelegate.m now looks like this :

```
// this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
// only valid if ProchainBus-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
// HACKED - stackoverflow.com/questions/8204308/phonegap-custom-url-handling-freezing
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url 
{
if (!url) { 
    return NO; 
}

// calls into javascript global function 'handleOpenURL'
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@
                      "window.setTimeout(function() { \n"
                      "handleOpenURL(\"%@\"); \n"
                      "},1);", url];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

// all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

return YES;    
}
```