# How do I handle a Custom URL Scheme in PhoneGap for a cold start?

Tags: cordova

I'm using handleOpenURL() for a Custom URL Scheme to launch my app from a link in an email. Works perfectly and I can do stuff in my app based on the URL parameters in the link.

The problem is handleOpenURL() doesn't seem to get call when my app does a cold start (not running in the background). Is there another handler that I can use for a cold start vs an already running instance?

OR

Is there a global variable that I can read that will tell me what the invoke URL was? I read about invokeString, but it never seems to be set?

I'm using PhoneGap 2.0

Comment: having the same problem in cordova 3.5 (yes, years have passed, I suppose it was fixed back in some versions). Now iOS deprecated handleOpenUrl etc meanwhile, still the valid answer below should work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you read carefully the comment above the application:handleOpenURL method, you will probably understand:

```
// this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
// only valid if Calinda-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
```

This methods will not be called if the application is not running. My solution was to tweak project with the following changes:

MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *URLToHandle;
@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*) theWebView 
{
     if (self.URLToHandle)
     {         
         NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.setTimeout(function() {handleOpenURL(\"%@\"); },1);", self.URLToHandle];
         [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
     }
     [...]
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.URLToHandle = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize URLToHandle;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{   
    [...]
    self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
    self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
    self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;

    // Patch for handleOpenURL
    ((MainViewController *)self.viewController).URLToHandle = URLToHandle;

    [...]
}
```

Hope that helps.

Cyril

Additional note: when testing make sure you stop xcode. When xcode was running application would throw an exception. if I stop the xcode this solution works fine.

Comment: I'm getting an error ("undeclared identifier: URLToHandle") in AppDelegate.m with this solution. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

By the way if anybody runs into this, The only thing missing is defining `URLToHandle` in `AppDelegate` (.h and .m) the same way it's been defined in `MainViewController`.

And also you have to reverse the assignment in `AppDelegate.m` from:

```
((MainViewController *)self.viewController).URLToHandle = URLToHandle;
```

to:

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.setTimeout(function() {handleOpenURL(\"%@\"); },1);", url];
((MainViewController *)self.viewController).URLToHandle = jsString;
```

you essentially have to transfer the url from `AppDelegate` to `MainViewController`.

`setTimeout` is critical otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Am not able to get this working, could you please put the final code snippet to be put in appdelegate and mvc. Thanks..